# Thinking of the fourier transform as a coordinate vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

From linear algebra we know that any vector can be associated to its coordinates in some basis.

After reading the defintion of the fourier transform this seem like exactly the same thing. Is it correct to think about $\hat{f}$ as a continous analouges of the coordinate vector $(a,b,c)$?

Comment: Yes, it's a continuous analogue of the coordinates with respect to a very special basis, the Fourier basis. (Strictly speaking this only makes sense for Fourier series but it is loosely still true for the Fourier transform.)

Comment: The **discrete** Fourier transform is a multiplication by some orthogonal/unitary matrix, ie. a change of basis. This basis allows to write the signal as a sum of (complex) sines. Letting $N \to \infty$ you'll obtain the Fourier series, but linear operators in infinite dimensional vector spaces are more complicated (as there are some convergence problems).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ah, so when taking the Fourier transform we really just pick some basis to represent our objects in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reasonable to think in this way, even though the objects in the integral are not in a vector space. The inner product behaves as expected:
$$
           \left\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}d\xi,
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{g}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}d\xi \right\rangle
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{g}(\xi)}d\xi.
$$
This is analogous to
$$
         \left\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n}\hat{g}(n)e^{inx}\right\rangle=\sum_{n}\hat{f}(n)\overline{\hat{g}(n)}.
$$
And,
$$
      f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}d\xi \\
       f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}
$$
This reason all of the orthogonality-related results seem to work so well is that you can approximate by the discrete case to any precision you like by choosing $\delta$ small enough:
$$
         f \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}e^{i\xi x}\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi
$$
And all of the pieces in the sum are mutually orthogonal in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. That's not an accident and it happens for classical eigenfunction expansions associated with Sturm-Liouville problems, though you may need to throw in a weight function (or measure) to be general enough.